# What does this "alarm" error mean?

Tags: c, memory, timer, signals, getrusage

I am trying to get the memory consumed by an algorithm, so I have created a group of functions that would stop the execution in periods of 10 milliseconds to let me read the memory using the getrusage() function. The idea is to set a timer that will raise an alarm signal to the process which will be received by a handler medir_memoria().

However, the program stops in the middle with this message:

```
[1]    3267 alarm    ./memory_test
```

The code for reading the memory is:

```
#include "../include/rastreador_memoria.h"

#if defined(__linux__) || defined(__APPLE__) || (defined(__unix__) && !defined(_WIN32))

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

static long max_data_size;
static long max_stack_size;

void medir_memoria (int sig)
{
    struct rusage info_memoria;

    if (getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &info_memoria) < 0)
    {
        perror("Not reading memory");
    }

    max_data_size = (info_memoria.ru_idrss > max_data_size) ? info_memoria.ru_idrss : max_data_size;
    max_stack_size = (info_memoria.ru_isrss > max_stack_size) ? info_memoria.ru_isrss : max_stack_size;

    signal(SIGALRM, medir_memoria);
}

void rastrear_memoria ()
{
    struct itimerval t;

    t.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    t.it_interval.tv_usec = 10;
    t.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    t.it_value.tv_usec = 10;

    max_data_size = 0;
    max_stack_size = 0;

    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &t,0);
    signal(SIGALRM, medir_memoria);
}

void detener_rastreo ()
{
    signal(SIGALRM, SIG_DFL);

    printf("Data: %ld\nStack: %ld\n", max_data_size, max_stack_size);
}

#else

#endif
```

The main() function works calling all of them in this order:

1. rastrear_memoria()
2. Function of the algorithm I am testing
3. detener_rastreo()

How can I solve this? What does that alarm message mean?

Answer (score 2):

First, setting an itimer to ring every 10 µs is optimistic, since ten microseconds is really a small interval of time. Try with 500 µs (or perhaps even 20 milliseconds, i.e. 20000 µs) instead of 10 µs first.

> stop the execution in periods of 10 milliseconds

You have coded for a period of 10 *micro*seconds, not milliseconds!

Then, you should exchange the two lines and code:

```
signal(SIGALRM, medir_memoria);
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &t,0);
```

so that a signal handler is set *before* the first itimer rings.

I guess your first itimer rings before the signal handler was installed. Read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). The default handling of `SIGALRM` is termination.

BTW, a better way to measure the time used by some function is [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) or [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html). Thanks to [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) tricks, `clock_gettime` is able to get some clock in less than 50 nanoseconds on my i5-4690S desktop computer.

> trying to get the memory consumed

You could consider using [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) e.g. opening, reading, and closing *quickly* `/proc/self/status` or `/proc/self/statm`  etc....

<sup>(I guess you are on Linux)</sup>

BTW, your measurements will disappoint you: notice that quite often [free(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html) don't release memory to the kernel (thru [munmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/munmap.2.html)...) but simply mark & manage that zone to be reusable by *future* [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html). You might consider [mallinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html) or [malloc_info(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_info.3.html) but notice that it is not async-signal-safe so cannot be called from inside a signal handler.

<sup>(I tend to believe that your approach is deeply flawed)</sup>